# C# Can we use async with using alias?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am working on a project for improve my skills. I am trying to code async and sync together. There is an issue I am curious about. We use "using" for disposable processings. Can we use "using" alias with await keyword?

This code block returned an error without use the "using". That's why I used "using".

```
public static async Task<string> AddAsync(IFormFile file, string filePath)
        {
            var sourcePath = Path.GetTempFileName();
            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                using (var stream = new FileStream(sourcePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }
                
            }

            File.Move(sourcePath, filePath);
            return filePath;
        }
```

Comment: without using `using`, what error do you have? Using `using` is usually not a must-do, without using it, the code may have memory leak issue but I've never seen an immediate error thrown by not using it.

Comment: A curious user; he can't reflect on himself.

Comment: @KingKing error message is "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process." I searched on the web, but those solutions weren't work for me. Then I used "using" and that code block started running.

Comment: actually you handle it wrong, you need to flush the stream first, using `using` will call the `Dispose` method and it will flush the stream for you. So after that the new file can be moved (renamed).

Comment: now it began to make sense, thank you for your attention @KingKing

Answer (score 1):

If you C# compiler is new enough it will emit the correct code for this. I remember when await was new and this didn't work; but if you're using any supported version of .NET Core this will work correctly.

The code generation has a surprising artifact; the using doesn't turn into a true finally block; if code above does something awful to the task it might not run (it turns into a dispose method on synthesized state object); but if you're using any of the normal patterns it will work.

The most obvious case of something awful is leaking the task; if the method throws and the task is leaked the Dispose never runs; but in this case you don't care because you don't need to clean up handles when the process is going to die anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your response, your response helped me to understand about this subject.

Comment: `C# compiler is new enough` - i.e., VS 2012 or newer. Only VS 2010 had this kind of compiler issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Can we use async with using alias?

Yes. All language constructs work as expected with `async` and `await`, including loops, `using`, `try`/`catch`/`finally`, etc. That's the whole point of `async` and `await`.